# Is TRUE/FALSE part of C standard?

Tags: c

`TRUE/FALSE` is usually defined in C as below. Are these definitions part of C standard which is supported by varies compiler implementations?

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard

Comment: @MarkRansom: Hardly. Some (IMO, stylistically very bad) C code uses macros like this. But it's far from universal. And the only places where they're defined by default are on certain Windows compilers with all kinds of non-standard stuff, and various low-quality compilers for random embedded systems, etc. :-)

Answer (score 9):

No for `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Yes for `true` and `false` in C99 or later if you include `<stdbool.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

C99 and C11 define an integral type with Boolean semantics called `_Bool`, but no actual true/false keywords exist.

The `_Bool` type is only capable of storing the values 1 and 0. Any value that doesn't compare equal to 0 is converted to 1, and any value comparing equal to 0 is converted to 0.

By including `<stdbool.h>`, the `_Bool` type is allowed to be written as `bool` as with some other languages, and `true` and `false` C preprocessor macros are defined to be 1 and 0 respectively.

Before that, it was somewhat of a convenience for someone to define constants like

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
typedef char BOOL; /* or #define BOOL char */
```

or sometimes

```
typedef enum {False, True} BOOL;
```

Unlike C99, however, both have at least one flaw:

```
BOOL bClicked = False;

++bClicked, ++bClicked;

if (bClicked == False)
    printf ("False\n");
else if (bClicked == True)
    printf ("True\n");
else
    printf ("Unknown: %d\n", bClicked);
```

That will print "Unknown: 2" because the defined `BOOL` type isn't a true Boolean type.

The C99 version:

```
_Bool bClicked = 0;

++bClicked, ++bClicked;

if (bClicked == 0)
  printf ("False\n");
else if (bClicked == 1)
  printf ("True\n");
else
  printf ("Unknown: %d\n", bClicked);
```

That will print "True" because `_Bool` can only store 0 and 1, so incrementing 1 to get 2, which compares as not equal to 0, results in 1.

Of course, most people just use the language to their advantage rather than actually comparing against True/False constants:

```
if (bClicked)
  {
    /* True if bClicked does not compare equal to 0 */
  }
else
  {
    /* False */
  }
```

Because of that behavior, there isn't any real need for a Boolean type or true/false constants; they exist purely for indication of intent.

I vaguely remember someone ranting that some Windows API functions return a value of type `BOOL`, but `TRUE` and `FALSE` weren't the only possible return values, so despite returning a value that should have been a simple comparison as in that last bit of code, more comparisons were needed to handle all possible cases. Had there been an actual Boolean type back then, most likely those functions, whatever they are/were would have returned a value of type `int` instead. A `BOOL` return type suggests only two values can be returned, but apparently that wasn't the case with those functions, perhaps because there was a third (error) return value.